# Powershell Script for looping through Azure Key Vault Issuance Policy

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault

I've a requirement - I need to get report of all certificate policies (Issuance Policy) and consolidate the report. Please see the 2nd image - these are the properties I'm looking in the report.

Solution using any technology is fine, mostly looking for - PowerShell, Azure Function etc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it helpful for you? If it is useful for you, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, if you want to get the Azure key vault, you use the PowerShell command [`Get-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultcertificatepolicy?view=azps-3.4.0) to get the information of the policy.

For example

1. Set access policy

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "<>"-ResourceGroupName "<>"-UserPrincipalName "<>" -PermissionsToCertificates get,list
```

2. Get policy

```
Get-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -VaultName "<>" -Name "<cert name>"
```

[image]

Besides, if you want to use Azure function to get the policy, please refer to the following steps

1. [Enable MSI for the Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?context=azure%2Factive-directory%2Fmanaged-identities-azure-resources%2Fcontext%2Fmsi-context&tabs=dotnet#adding-a-system-assigned-identity)
   [image]
   [image]
2. Set access policy

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "<>"-ResourceGroupName "<>" -ObjectId "<the object id you copy>"  -PermissionsToCertificates get,list
```

3. Code(C#)

```
//install package Azure.Identity Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates
  CertificateClient client = new CertificateClient(new Uri("https://norasvault.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());

Response<CertificatePolicy> result =await client.GetCertificatePolicyAsync("yangtest");

// create the report
// the result.value cantians the properties of  CertificatePolicy
```

For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.certificates.certificatepolicy?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @Avinash Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: @Avinash Could you please tell me the error message?